# How to use \Large and its variants

Tags: fontsize

I came across a [German LaTeX page](http://www.namsu.de/latex/kapitel5_1.html) and found instructions like:

1. `\Large{bit bigger}`
2. `{\Large a bit bigger}`
3. `\begin{Large} ... \end{Large}`

Is it true that all three are "correct"? I only remember the second one being correct for 1) `\Large` and others don't take an argument and perhaps I forgot about 3). Can somebody enlighten me?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You are indeed correct.  The `\Large` command and its ilk change the font size for everything following them up until the end of the group, just like `\color{red}`.  This means that `\Large{bit bigger}` will appear to work in certain cases, since it's parsed as two things: first, the command `\Large`, and second, the group `{bit bigger}`.  The difference—and the reason that #1 is incorrect—is easy to see: compare

```
In this sentence, {\Large only some text is large} and the rest is normal.
```

and

```
In this sentence, \Large{too much text is large}, including this.
```

The former renders as

[image: Good usage of \Large.]

The latter, however, renders as

[image: Bad usage of \Large.]

This is a useful property of `\Large` and its friends; for instance, to get a list in a larger font size, one can write simply

```
\begin{itemize}
  \Large
  \item Alpha
  \item Beta
  \item Gamma
\end{itemize}
```

Now, as for the third usage, it's true that `\begin{Large}` and `\end{Large}` will work, even though `\Large` is not defined as an environment.  To see why this works, consider the `\begin` and `\end` commands.  What `\begin` does is expand to some boilerplate (for error checking and the like), then `\begingroup`, and then `\csname#1\endcsname`.  Conversely, aside from the boilerplate, `\end` expands to `\csname end#1\endcsname`, and then `\endgroup`.  Writing `\csname foo\endcsname` is almost exactly like writing `\foo`, except with one important difference: if `\foo` is undefined, it's `\let` to `\relax` (the command which does nothing).  This means that when you write `\begin{Large} Some text here \end{Large}`, this is roughly equivalent to `\begingroup\Large some text here \relax\endgroup`.  Thus, even though `\endLarge` isn't defined, the environment functions just as well.  Note that this ability to use switches as environments is apparently documented in Leslie Lamport's book, although I've never had the chance to read it myself; [Philipp's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/how-to-use-large-et-al/7314#7314) clarifies the pitfalls of using switches as environments.

Comment: @Antal S-Z: Excellent answer! Is the `\Large` scoping the same as e.g. `\textit` or `\textbf` --- the `\textbf{too much text} this is also bold`? If not, how do you know which commands have the `\Large` type of scope and which have the `\textbf` type of scope?

Comment: That switches can be used as environments is not an accident, but is documented in Lamport's book.

Comment: @Brian M. Hunt: All font-switching commands that start with `\text…` or `\math…` take an argument, all other font-switching commands (`\itshape` etc.) take effect until the end of the current group.

Comment: @Philipp: Thanks for that—sadly, I've never read his book.  I'll edit that into my answer.  (If you have a quote or page number reference, that'd be appreciated for clarity's sake.)

Comment: @Brian: To add to what Philipp said, the difference between the two commands is how they're defined.  The `\textbf`-style commands are defined to take a single argument, which they then style.  The `\Large`-style commands take no arguments, but change how things are to be formatted.  The only way to tell the difference in general is to look at the definitions or documentation, but Philipp's comment is exactly correct for the standard commands.

Comment: @Philipp & @Antal S-Z: Got it - Thanks!

Comment: Note: In Lamport's LaTeX Manual, section 2.2.5 "Declarations", it is said that `\begin{em} ... \end{em}` is equivalent to `{\em ...}`, and the former is clearer. However, as @Philipp said, it does have some pitfalls, and should be used with care.

Comment: Small correction: the \begingroup comes before not after the \csname in the expansion of \begin

Answer (score 21):

The first is incorrect. The second one is correct. The third version works, but has a few (possible) issues: Spaces after the first closing brace are not ignored (unlike other environments), and if the content contains a whole paragraph, the paragraph end must be inside the environment.

Comment: side note, the explanation for why the paragraph end must be inside the group is in [paragraphs - Temporarily increase line spacing - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48741/temporarily-increase-line-spacing/48743#48743)

Answer (score 6):

All the font-sizing commands like `\Large` are defined in the `.clo` files that the standard classes loads, when you specify for example the font size parameter in an article class. They are defined as:

```
 \newcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xviipt{22}}
```

As you can see the macro does not take a parameter and hence the correct usage would be to use it as a switch or just enclose it in brackets.