# Description-like environment with fixed labels width

Tags: lists, indentation, description

Which is the right way to do something like 'description' list but with customizable and fixed-width labels? I.e. something like this:

```
Label:         Text text text text text text
               text text text text.
Longer label:  Text text text text text text
               Text text text text.
```

The way I see it to use two-column table (first columt for labels and second column for descriptions), but this solution seems ugly.
Is there any other way?

Comment: Related question: [how to control `enumitem`'s description list via `leftmargin` and `labelwidth` keys](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23559/how-to-control-enumitems-description-list-via-leftmargin-and-labelwidth-keys)

Comment: I want to get the opposite of this! How on earth did you manage to get flexible width of the label column working? :S

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to customize the `description` environment, *e.g.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=8em,style=nextline]
  \item[Something] Text. More text.More text.More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. 
  \item[Ought else] More text.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can set this for all `description` environments (probably not desirable) with

```
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=8em,style=nextline}
```

or you can define your own list environment *e.g.*

```
\newlist{NewDesc}{description}{2}
\setlist[NewDesc]{leftmargin=8em,style=nextline}
```

and use as

```
\begin{NewDesc}
  \item[Something] Text. More text.More text.More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. 
  \item[Ought else] More text.
\end{NewDesc}
```

Comment: Enumitem package works excellent for me.

Answer (score 11):

The [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes and the `scrextend` package (part of `KOMA-Script`) provide the `labeling` list environment. It takes the length of the longest label as mandatory argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\addtokomafont{labelinglabel}{\sffamily\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{labeling}{Longer label\quad}
\item[Label] Some text.
\item[Longer label] Some text.
\end{labeling}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Another way, far less elegant to what [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) is to use a `tabular`-related structure.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}>{\bfseries}p{8em}<{:}}% Item label
\newcolumntype{I}{X@{}}% Item contents
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{LI}
  Label & \lipsum[1] \\
  Longer label & \lipsum[2]
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

In the above example, [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) was used to have a table with flexible columns to the maximum text block width (`\textwidth`). Additionally, the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) provides a means to insert code before/after column entries. This way it is possible to format the first column entries `#1` as `\bfseries#1:` (automatically prepending a **bold** format and appending a colon `:`). Finally, the outer column spacing was removed using a `@{}` column specifier.

The drawbacks are:

- The `tabular` does not flow across page breaks; and
- It's interface is not as easy as list with special sequences required to distinguish item labels and contents (`&`) and "new items" (`\\`).

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) merely provided some dummy text.

Answer (score 3):

This may be useful. If you don't use [`IEEEtran`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran) document class, you can use the [`IEEEtrantools`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/tools) package.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
% \documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\begin{document}
    \begin{IEEEdescription}[\IEEEsetlabelwidth{The longest Label}] % Longest label goes here as an argument!
        \item[Label] First item
        \item[Longer Label] Second item, text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text!
        \item[The longest Label] Third item
    \end{IEEEdescription}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, inspired by Torbjørn T.'s answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{Description}{description}{3}
\setlist[Description]{style=nextline}
\SetEnumitemKey{margin}{leftmargin={\widthof{#1}+2em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Description}[margin=longer label]
\item[label] Text. More text.More text.More text. More text. More text.   More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. More text. 
\item[longer label] More text.
\end{Description}

\end{document}
```