# How can I make a command/environment for a titled paragraph but with the text indented to the title (picture inside)?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

Basically I want to make this:

```
**The title**    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam
                 vestibulum accumsan nisl. Phasellus lacus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                 amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
```

Picture:

[image: indented paragraph with a title]

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/description-like-environment-with-fixed-labels-width

Comment: That was it. Thanks! So... how do I mark the question as solved?

Comment: It will be likely closed as a duplicate, so that all answers are (still) collected in a single place (the original question). Duplicates don't count as "unanswered".