# Align text under a colon

Tags: indentation

In plain text, this is what I want to do:

```
Explanation: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus volutpat eu orci vitae eleifend.
             Praesent sed orci commodo, venenatis neque vel, pulvinar velit.
             Mauris ullamcorper tellus sed quam pellentesque, vitae sagittis nisl dapibus.
```

### update

If `hspace{5cm}` fit the length of the word "Explanation: " and if `hspace` worked in the enumerate environment, the following would be what I want my document to look like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item 1

answer

\item 2

explanation: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus volutpat eu orci vitae eleifend.\\ \hspace {5cm}Praesent sed orci commodo, venenatis neque vel, pulvinar velit.\\ \hspace {5cm}Mauris ullamcorper tellus sed quam pellentesque, vitae sagittis nisl dapibus.

\item 3

answer

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Basically, imagine

```
Explanation: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus volutpat eu orci vitae eleifend.
             Praesent sed orci commodo, venenatis neque vel, pulvinar velit.
             Mauris ullamcorper tellus sed quam pellentesque, vitae sagittis nisl dapibus.
```

is in an enumerate environment.

This is what I want:

[image: img]

Comment: Plain text or Plain TeX? Are you interested in page breaking capability for the right-hand text? Have you seen the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for list management? Do you know of tabular environments like [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)?

Comment: *EDIT:* Yes, what @TorbjørnT. said. Much better. Don't abuse tables.

Comment: Something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/description-like-environment-with-fixed-labels-width/33818#33818?

Comment: removed the `align` tag, as that is specifically for math. `horizontal-alignment` might work, but it's really the indentation (`\hangindent` would be appropriate if this were plain tex) that's involved here.

Comment: I was saying "plain text" to refer to my presentation of the formatting on this question. But I mean I want to use that in a LaTeX article.

Comment: From comment trail below, still not clear what you want it to look like. If you want numbers before the hanging part but without a straightforward numbering scheme you could define your own counter in conjunction with the below. Show a picture of your ideal output.

Comment: I've added an image.

Comment: See revised answer based on revised question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Revised answer based on revised question. There are many ways to skin a cat. Here are two possible ways that might provide some inspiration.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newlength{\hangwidth}
\newcommand{\newhang}[1]{\settowidth{\hangwidth}{#1}\par\hangpara{\hangwidth}{1}#1}
\newcounter{myquestion}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{myquestion} 
\newhang{\arabic{myquestion}. Question: }What is the question?
\newhang{Answer: }Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\Phasellus volutpat eu orci vitae eleifend.\\Praesent sed orci commodo, venenatis neque vel, pulvinar velit.\\Mauris ullamcorper tellus sed quam pellentesque, vitae sagittis nisl dapibus.
\stepcounter{myquestion} 
\newhang{\arabic{myquestion}. Question: }What is the question?
\newhang{Answer: }Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\Phasellus volutpat eu orci vitae eleifend.\\Praesent sed orci commodo, venenatis neque vel, pulvinar velit.\\Mauris ullamcorper tellus sed quam pellentesque, vitae sagittis nisl dapibus.
\stepcounter{myquestion} 
\newhang{\arabic{myquestion}. Question: }What is the question?
\newhang{Answer: }Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\Phasellus volutpat eu orci vitae eleifend.\\Praesent sed orci commodo, venenatis neque vel, pulvinar velit.\\Mauris ullamcorper tellus sed quam pellentesque, vitae sagittis nisl dapibus.

\setcounter{myquestion}{0}
\begin{longtable}{rp{0.7\textwidth}}
\stepcounter{myquestion}\arabic{myquestion}. Question: &What is the question?\\
Answer: &Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus volutpat eu orci vitae eleifend. Praesent sed orci commodo, venenatis neque vel, pulvinar velit. Mauris ullamcorper tellus sed quam pellentesque, vitae sagittis nisl dapibus.\\
\stepcounter{myquestion}\arabic{myquestion}. Question: &What is the question?\\
Answer: &Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus volutpat eu orci vitae eleifend. Praesent sed orci commodo, venenatis neque vel, pulvinar velit. Mauris ullamcorper tellus sed quam pellentesque, vitae sagittis nisl dapibus.\\
\stepcounter{myquestion}\arabic{myquestion}. Question: &What is the question?\\
Answer: &Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus volutpat eu orci vitae eleifend. Praesent sed orci commodo, venenatis neque vel, pulvinar velit. Mauris ullamcorper tellus sed quam pellentesque, vitae sagittis nisl dapibus.\\
\stepcounter{myquestion}\arabic{myquestion}. Question: &What is the question?\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works by itself, but within the `enumerate` environment, it doesn't work. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: You said you wanted it in plain text. How do you want it to look in the enumerate environment?

Comment: I was saying "plain text" to refer to my presentation of the formatting on this question. But I mean I want to use that in a LaTeX article.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But the output I produced is identical to your required output. Why would you want to put this in an enumerate environment? Do you want a number in front of it?

Comment: I am writing up homework solutions. This is under #2.

Comment: You need to show an example of exactly how you want it to look, if different from your question.

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 1):

A quick hacky way to achieve this is with `phantom` which produces space equivalent to how much its argument would have it wasn't `phantom`'d.

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Question\\
  explanation: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus.\\
  \phantom{explanation:} Praesent sed orci commodo.\\
  \phantom{explanation:} Mauris ullamcorper tellus sed quam pellentesque, vitae sagittis.
\end{enumerate}
```

gives me (in Beamer):

[image]