# Descriptions is written overtop the text

Tags: description

Its the first time to use description but there the description overlay the text as shown here[image]

this is the script I'm using:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\ifCLASSINFOpdf


\else


\fi


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}



\begin{document}


\title{A}


\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{}}


\maketitle


\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle




\begin{description}
  \item[Experiment 1 :] In this experiment, aaaa
  \item[Experiment 2 :]   This experiment is the same as Experiment 1, but
  \item[Experiment 3 :] This experiment is the same as Experiment 1, but the
\end{description}

\bibliography{../refhJ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems like [Description-like environment with fixed labels width](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/description-like-environment-with-fixed-labels-width) would solve your problem.

Comment: Please post a Minimal Working Example demonstrating your issue. If I copy your code into an empty article and compile, it looks fine. No overlap at all. So the problem is something beyond what you are showing. Make sure your code compiles as posted and that it shows the issue as posted. Otherwise, we really can have no idea.

Comment: @cfr Thanks, I've updated the question and put the whole document so if you could have a look

Comment: In the future, MWEs are most helpful when you also remove the extraneous packages and text that are irrelevant to the problem at hand.  See [how to minimalize your MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/47522) for more great information in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `\usepackage{enumitem}` to the preamble and then define your list with `\begin{description}[leftmargin=8em,style=nextline]`, you can get rid of your problem, as described in [Description-like environment with fixed labels width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/description-like-environment-with-fixed-labels-width).

A full example:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\ifCLASSINFOpdf


\else


\fi


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}



\begin{document}


\title{A}


\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{}}


\maketitle


\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle




\begin{description}[leftmargin=8em,style=nextline]
  \item[Experiment 1 :] In this experiment, aaaa
  \item[Experiment 2 :]   This experiment is the same as Experiment 1, but
  \item[Experiment 3 :] This experiment is the same as Experiment 1, but the
\end{description}

\bibliography{../refhJ}

\end{document}
```

displays the list as:

[image: description list]