# How can I achieve this aligned two-column word-list-like layout?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, two-column

This is my first tex question. I couldn't find a duplicate since I'm not even sure how to describe this layout in English...It looks like this:

```
[item1]     [explanation of item1......may be very long
            accross several lines, may contain math, and
            need to be wrapped automatically]

[item2]     [explanation of item2.......................
            ............................................
            ....................]
```

The space between items and explanations should be adjustable (usually several tabs in vim).

I have tried the alltt package and use tabs(spaces) to get the layout, however, it cannot do automatic line wrapping and I have to manually break lines, so that's not really a solution.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/ help?

Comment: You may want to look at the `glossaries` package or the various `description` list types offered.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Wow, you are so quick! Even before I finish editing my question! Seems that it helps, will try it soon.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It solves my problem prefectly. Thank you.