# Alignment of long item labels

Tags: indentation, enumerate

I tried looking for this but I honestly could not find anything for my particular issue.

I am designing a poster in LaTeX and I sometimes use custom list items. The thing is, as these get wider, they take up space to the **left** instead of the **right** as I would like them to.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is a normal item
    \item[Blablablabla]{This is a large item} 
\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: you should not be using `[...]` arguments to `\item` when using `enumerate`, consider using `description` instead. Also see the `enumitem` package for full control over lists.

Comment: Are you after something like this? [Description-like environment with fixed labels width](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33818)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This is perfect. How can I accept your answer? Mind flagging the question as duplicate of the one in your link?

Comment: Good to hear. I voted to close, so when four others cast their vote, it will be closed.