# How to produce side by side item and description

Tags: layout

What I'd like to do is this:

```
Item 1: description description description description description % edge of page
        description description description description description
        description description description description description

Item 2: description description description description description 
        description description description description description
        description description description description description
```

etc. with the description wrapping at the edge of the page but not starting at the beginning of the line. I'm fairly new to Latex not even sure what to google here to find the answer. Hopefully someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What should "Item 1" and "Item 2" be replaced with? Bulletpoints, numbers or a word/text?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What would be the real text of the  labels? An enumeration?

Comment: The name of the item (ie just text) rather than a symbol

Comment: `\begin{itemize}\item[Item 1:] description description description \item[Item 2:] description description description... \end{itemize}` should give something similar... You need to add `\usepackage{enumitem}` in your preamble...

Comment: Are all "Item..." texts (labels) equally long? If not, do you want to indent the description text with respect to the corresponding label or with respect to the longest label inside of the same list?

Comment: I would use a `tabularx` environment , like this `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}rX@{}} Item 1& description description description … \\ Item 2 & …… \end{tabularx}`

Comment: @leandriis ideally indent with respect to longest label

Comment: thanks @Bernard I'll try it

Comment: [Description-like environment with fixed labels width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33817/134144) seems to be related.

Comment: yes it does indeed thanks