# list item multilined ( `\newline` inside of item label ?)

Tags: lists, line-breaking, itemize

How to make multiline item label ?

Example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[Great Item] \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I would love to do

```
\item[Great \newline Item] \lipsum[1]
```

But I does not work.

Expected result - first lines of litem label and item content aligned:

```
Great   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
Item    consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        Ut purus elit, ver...
```

---

To be more specific I use `mydesc` environment provided at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23569/7128 .
I would love to make it work together.
Above example is overslimplified.
Here is more detailed :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% mydesc thanks for https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23569/7128
\newenvironment{mydesc}[1]
  {\list{}{\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\it##1\hfil}%
     \settowidth\labelwidth{\makelabel{\it#1}}%
     \setlength\leftmargin{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}}}
  {\endlist}
\begin{document}
\begin{mydesc}{LongestItem}
\item[Great Item] \lipsum[1]
\end{mydesc}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LaTeX offers a command `\shortstack` for this kind of thing, so your solution could look like this:

```
\item[\smash{\shortstack[l]{Great\\Item}}] \lipsum[1]
```

Unfortunately, `\shortstack` is bottom-aligned by default, so we have to hack a "top" variant:

```
\makeatletter
\gdef\tshortstack{\@ifnextchar[\@tshortstack{\@tshortstack[c]}}
\gdef\@tshortstack[#1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vtop\bgroup
    \baselineskip-\p@\lineskip 3\p@
    \let\mb@l\hss\let\mb@r\hss
    \expandafter\let\csname mb@#1\endcsname\relax
    \let\\\@stackcr
    \@ishortstack}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\smash{\tshortstack[l]{Great\\Item}}] \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

The code for `\tshortstack` was just copied from the respective code in the LaTeX sources. If you don't want to copy so much code, you can also use `\patchcmd`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\gdef\tshortstack{\@ifnextchar[\@tshortstack{\@tshortstack[c]}}
\let\@tshortstack\@shortstack
\patchcmd\@tshortstack\vbox\vtop{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[\smash{\tshortstack[l]{Great\\Item}}] \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki I forgot to copy `\makeatletter` in the first version of my code. Please try again.

Comment: Dang it, the results (at least in my case) look God awful. I decide to move part of the item's label to its description as well as (for a different item) just to split it into two items.