# Glossaries: vertical aligment of acronyms' long names

Tags: glossaries

How can I vertically align entries in my acronyms' list? I use the Glossaries package to generate it.
Here is MWE:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
% !TeX encoding = utf-8
% !TeX spellcheck = ru_RU

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[xindy={glsnumbers=false}, nonumberlist, nopostdot, nogroupskip]{glossaries}
%\setglossarystyle{super} % uncomment for style "super"
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newacronym{bam}{ДАП}{Двунаправленная Ассоциативная Память}
\newacronym{ai}{ИИ}{Искусственный Интеллект}
\newacronym{am}{АП}{Ассоциативная Память}
\newacronym{ann}{ИНС}{Искусственная Нейронная Сеть}
\newacronym{an}{ИН}{Искусственный Нейрон}
\newacronym{it}{ИТ}{Информационные Технологии}
\glsaddall

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

With the default style I have the following:
[image: default style]
As you can see, the long names are not vertically aligned.
What I want can be achieved with the

```
\setglossarystyle{super}
```

But it this case, short names lose the BOLDness, some small horizontal indent appears and the spacing between lines becomes smaller:
[image: super style]
where RED is some extra indent, which I don't need.
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Please **complete** your code and post a small, complete document which compiles to demonstrate the problem. This is much more useful than a mere fragment or images.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The super style uses a [supertabular](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/supertabular) table. This is different from the standard `description` list in the standard style. The table that is created is centered on the page causing the indentation. The bold is lost because the default behavior for `description` lists is that `\item[name] desc` will cause `name` to be bold.

There are a few ways to fix this. I used two methods, one based on a table and one based on a description list.

(Note: I will be using DejaVu Serif (font I have for Cyrillic letters). Also, "Glossary" appears as the header and I assume this has something to do with my local setup, and will appear properly for you)

### Table Method

There are a few ways to fix this the first is to change the table style to allow bold and to modify some lengths to get the format you want. In general, the [longtable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package is used over [supertabular](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/supertabular) and I modified the `long` style for the custom style you are looking for.

Using the `\setglossarystyle{long}` and just before `\printglossaries` adding:

```
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\glsdescwidth{0.8\hsize}
```

will fix the issue with the centered table, by removing the left and right margins. Setting `\glsdescwidth` to `0.8\hsize` (default `0.6\hsize`) gave more room for the description in the table.

To fix the bold issues is a bit more difficult as you have to define a custom style. You can base it off of an existing style such as `long` and change only the `\glossentry` by adding the following to the preamble before `\setglossarystyle`:

```
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\bfseries \glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}
```

In addition you need to set the  glossary style with `\setglossarystyle{mylong}` to use the custom style. The only difference between this and what is defined in `glossary-super.sty` (part of glossaries) for `long` is the addition of `\bfseries`.

**Edit:** A better method as noted by Nicola Talbot is to simply use `long` as the table style and `\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}` to fix the bold issue.

The full mwe is (with the original bold method commented out) :

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVu Serif}

\usepackage[xindy={glsnumbers=false}, nonumberlist, nopostdot, nogroupskip]{glossaries}

% Original method for bold
%\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
%  \setglossarystyle{long}%
%  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
%    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\bfseries \glossentryname{##1}} &
%    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
%  }%
%}
%\setglossarystyle{mylong}

% Nicola Talbot's suggestion
\setglossarystyle{long}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newacronym{bam}{ДАП}{Двунаправленная Ассоциативная Память}
\newacronym{ai}{ИИ}{Искусственный Интеллект}
\newacronym{am}{АП}{Ассоциативная Память}
\newacronym{ann}{ИНС}{Искусственная Нейронная Сеть}
\newacronym{an}{ИН}{Искусственный Нейрон}
\newacronym{it}{ИТ}{Информационные Технологии}
\glsaddall

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\glsdescwidth{0.8\hsize}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

and produces:
[image: Table MWE result]

### Description List Method

My preferred method would be to modify the description list using the [enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package. Using the `\setlist` command from [enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) can change the format of all description lists and used as:

```
\setlist[description]{leftmargin=!, labelwidth=3em} % Change for glossaries
\printglossaries
\setlist[description]{style=standard} % reset settings back to default
```

By wrapping `\printglossaries` with `\setlist[description]`, the width of the label can be changed without modifying the style, and can easily be set differently for multiple `\printglossary` commands. For this example setting `labelwidth=3em` is appropriate, but may need to be changed depending on the acronyms used.

The full mwe is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{DejaVu Serif}

\usepackage[xindy={glsnumbers=false}, nonumberlist, nopostdot, nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newacronym{bam}{ДАП}{Двунаправленная Ассоциативная Память}
\newacronym{ai}{ИИ}{Искусственный Интеллект}
\newacronym{am}{АП}{Ассоциативная Память}
\newacronym{ann}{ИНС}{Искусственная Нейронная Сеть}
\newacronym{an}{ИН}{Искусственный Нейрон}
\newacronym{it}{ИТ}{Информационные Технологии}
\glsaddall

\setlist[description]{leftmargin=!, labelwidth=3em} % Change for glossaries
\printglossaries
\setlist[description]{style=standard} % reset settings back to default

\end{document}
```

resulting in:
[image: result using list method]

For more on enumitems description lists see: [How to control enumitem's description list via leftmargin and labelwidth keys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23559/how-to-control-enumitems-description-list-via-leftmargin-and-labelwidth-keys) and [Description-like environment with fixed labels width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/description-like-environment-with-fixed-labels-width)

Comment: For the bold name in the `long` style you could just redefine `\glsnamefont` to use bold, e.g. `\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot that is much better, I will fix that.

Comment: The description list method saved my day!