# Vertically alignment of glossary, \setlist[description]: ! Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: errors, vertical-alignment, glossaries, enumitem

I want to vertically align the list of abbreviations following this link [Glossaries: vertical aligment of acronyms' long names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178507/glossaries-vertical-aligment-of-acronyms-long-names). I like the second method of the answer "Description List Method", so I tried with the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[xindy={glsnumbers=false}, acronym, nogroupskip, nonumberlist, nopostdot]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{cpu}{CPU}{Central Processing Unit}
\newacronym{jpeg}{JPEG}{Joint Photographic Experts Group}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\setlist[description]{leftmargin=!, labelwidth=3em}
\printacronyms
\setlist[description]{style=standard}

\end{document}
```

But I got an error saying something wrong with the command \setlist[description]:

```
#:latex latexT.tex
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
(./latexT.tex
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
Babel <v3.8h> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, nohyphenation, arabic, basque, bulgarian, coptic, welsh, czech, slovak, german, ngerman, danish, esperanto, spanish, catalan, galician, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, greek, monogreek, ancientgreek, croatian, hungarian, interlingua, ibycus, indonesian, icelandic, italian, latin, mongolian, dutch, norsk, polish, portuguese, pinyin, romanian, russian, slovenian, uppersorbian, serbian, swedish, turkish, ukenglish, ukrainian, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)) (./glossaries.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex)) (./mfirstuc.sty
(./etoolbox.sty (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/etex/etex.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty) (./xfor.sty)
(./datatool-base.sty (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty)

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 48, version
               `2009/10/20' of package substr,
               but only version
               `2005/11/29 v1.1 Handle substrings'
               is available.

(./datatool-fp.sty (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty)))) (./glossaries-compatible-307.sty) (./glossary-hypernav.sty) (./glossary-list.sty) (./glossary-long.sty (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)) (./glossary-super.sty (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty)) (./glossary-tree.sty)) (./latexT.aux) (./latexT.glsdefs)
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   d
l.16 \setlist[description]
                          {leftmargin=!, labelwidth=3em}
?
```

Does anyone know where goes wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You need to [update your distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764). After doing that, try again.

Comment: ...you still need to update your distribution...

Comment: Nice first question. MWE and all :)

Comment: Hi, thank you Werner, it works on newer version. Thank you Feldman :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is solved by a distribution update.