# How do I increase the space between the abbreviation and definition?

Tags: spacing, glossaries, acronyms

I'm using the glossaries package to create a list of abbreviations. 
I would like to set the horizontal space between the abbreviation and definition to 2.5 cm. I realise this question has been asked previously but I was not able to find a solution that fits the simple example below.

Here is a MWE. Thanking you in advance!

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[acronym, sort=use, nopostdot, nonumberlist, hyperfirst=false]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{List of Abbreviations}
\newacronym{who}{WHO}{World Health Office}
\newacronym{oth}{OTHER}{Some disease other than Response System}
\newacronym{sar}{SARI}{Severe acute something infection}
\newacronym{vid}{VIDAL}{Another very very other long acronym}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries
First use: \gls{who}. Second use: \gls{who}. Now we move on to \gls{sar} this is the first mention so when i use \gls{sar} again we get the short version. I also discuss \gls{vid} of course too

\end{document}
```

The output is attached. I just want to increase the space between acronym and its definition to 2.5 cm [image: Space is too small]

Comment: Please check my answer and the original answer to see if it fits your needs. If so, tell as to mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Do you want the descriptions vertically aligned (as though in a table) or do you simply want to increase the gap between the end of the name and the start of the description (maintaining a ragged effect)?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Yes, I do want the descriptions vertically aligned. thank you for clarifying. Can  achieve that modifying the code suggested by LianTze below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the absolute separation distance between each acronym and its description needs to be 2.5cm? That's quite wide, but adding these in the preamble should do it:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\theglossary}
  {\begin{description}}
  {\begin{description}[labelsep=2.5cm]}{}{}
```

If you mean you need every label to occupy a width of 2.5cm, then you can change `labelsep` to `labelwidth`.

Comment: This works, however I get a red corss next to the two last lines of code and when I hover the mouse over them there is a message that says:      
unexpected close group } after \begin {description}

Answer (score 0):

In my answer I just used the answer of @AlexGrede from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179993/120578) so please don't upvote... I am voting to close the question if OP says it is ok.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[xindy={glsnumbers=false}, nonumberlist, nopostdot, nogroupskip]{glossaries}

% Original method for bold
%\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
%  \setglossarystyle{long}%
%  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
%    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\bfseries \glossentryname{##1}} &
%    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
%  }%
%}
%\setglossarystyle{mylong}

% Nicola Talbot's suggestion
\setglossarystyle{long}
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand*{\acronymname}{List of Abbreviations}
\newacronym{who}{WHO}{World Health Office}
\newacronym{oth}{OTHER}{Some disease other than Response System}
\newacronym{sar}{SARI}{Severe acute something infection}
\newacronym{vid}{VIDAL}{Another very very other long acronym}

\begin{document}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\glsdescwidth{0.8\hsize}
\printglossaries

First use: \gls{who}. Second use: \gls{who}. Now we move on to \gls{sar} this is the first mention so when i use \gls{sar} again we get the short version. I also discuss \gls{vid} of course too

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my output the distance between items is less than 2.5 cm. Are you able to point out where you set that value?

Comment: Tried but not.. Sorry. I am just leaving the answer to let people know the problem. I thought about hidding a long acronym but didn't made it to work yet. Leaving the answer for futer people to use the idea if they manage to do it

Comment: It seemed like something so simple to set, but clearly it is not :(

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question:- "This works, however I get a red corss next to the two last lines of code and when I hover the mouse over them there is a message that says: unexpected close group } after \begin {description}"

You need to use this in the file where you have all the abbreviations. At the top, use:-
\begin{description}[labelwidth=2.5cm]{}{}

WRITE ABBREVIATIONS

\end{desciption}