# Multiline right hand side in align environment

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath, cases

Consider the working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        (a+b)^2 &= a^2 + 2ab + b^2\\
        (a-b)^2 &= a^2 - 2ab + b^2
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

What I need is to draw `}` at the right hand side that will cover both the lines, follwoed by some text. This image represents what I wanted (given in red).

[image]

I don't have a clue on how to get started (so, there is no code that I tried).

Comment: Seatch this site for solutions using the `\tizmark` library. That will not only help you get his done but also set you up for solving a lot of similar issues.  [Multiline brackets within a {description} environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211197/4301) is an answer that shows how to solve a similar requirement for a list environment. Even though it is a different environment the idea is the same: place mark at the approraite points on the page that you can later access and do the drawing.

Comment: There are solutions that work without using `\tikzmark` as well, but those won't be usable in as many cases as `\tikzmark` will be and may not be as easy to customize in terms of colors, shading, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two main options: (a) an `array` environment, and (b) an `rcases` environment; the latter is provided by the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools) package. As the following screenshot shows, they produce the same *horizontal* layout. If you look closely, the line spacing with the `rcases` option is a bit more generous than it is for `array` option. The increase in vertical spacing may -- or may not -- be to your liking.

In fact, due to the use of an `aligned` environment to encase the equations, a *third option* is available as well: (c) don't use either `array` or `rcases` -- `\left. \blurb \right\}` suffices fully. Many thanks to [Donald Arseneau](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/208556/donald-arseneau) for pointing this out in a comment.

[image]

For the case at hand (pun intended), using the `rcases` environment may be a bit of overkill as the test code doesn't make use of many of the environment's capabilities.

If you need the word "sum" to be typeset in red, be sure to (i) load the `xcolor` package in the preamble and (ii) change `\text{sum}` to `\text{\color{red}sum}`. If the right-hand curly brace also needs to be rendered in red, you can't use the `rcases` solution ("option B") and you'll need to type `\color{red}\right\}` and `\text{\color{red}sum}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'rcases' environment
\newcommand\blurb{% 
% material that's common to all three options:
    \begin{aligned}
        (a+b)^2 &= a^2 + 2ab + b^2\\
        (a-b)^2 &= a^2 - 2ab + b^2
    \end{aligned}
}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
%% Option A: 'array' environment
    \left. \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
       \blurb
    \end{array} \right\}
    &\text{sum} 
    \\[1ex]
%% Option B: 'rcases' environment
    \begin{rcases}
       \blurb
    \end{rcases}
    &\text{sum}
    \\[1ex]
%% Option C: no encasing environment
    \left. 
       \blurb
    \right\}
    &\text{sum} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the array for? You are using aligned already. Making the brace red eliminates rcases. `\left. \blurb \color{red}\right\} \text{\color{red}sum}`.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau - Many thanks for pointing out that `array` isn't strictly needed. I've edited the answer to provide the no-`array` setup (`\left. \blurb \right\}`) as a third option. I didn't delete the `array` option entirely as the OP may (or may not)! be interested in getting slightly tighter line spacing.

Answer (score 4):

Still another short way, with `empheq` (which loads `mathtools`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 

\begin{document}

    \begin{empheq}[right=\color{Coral}\empheqrbrace \textsf{sum}]{align*}
        (a+b)^2 &= a^2 + 2ab + b^2\\
        (a-b)^2 &= a^2 - 2ab + b^2
    \end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]