# Font sizes and line height: how/when/why do \Huge, \LARGE, etc. affect one or the other?

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inconsistent line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36454/inconsistent-line-spacing)

In the following MWE, the first paragraph has a quite tight line-spacing.
The second paragraph has a larger line-spacing, which I accidentally used for my title, but is actually the intended layout.
It appears font-size commands affect font-size inside the group, but line-spacing for the entire paragraph.

Is my understanding correct?
How, where, and why do font-size commands affect font-sizes and line heights?
What is the underlying system here?
What is the correct usage of font-size commands in this context?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{savetrees} % just so example fits on a page; not essential for MWE
\begin{document}
{\LARGE \blindtext}

\Huge {\LARGE \blindtext}
\end{document}
```

Output using `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)` and `article 2007/10/19 v1.4h`:

[image: linespacing example]

Related question: [How to use \Large and its variants](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/how-to-use-large-et-al)

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36454/inconsistent-line-spacing). You apparently have to tell TeX that a group contains a paragraph using `\par`, else it's treated as just inline text.

Comment: If you use nested commands of fontsizes you need to tell TeX where to make a paragraph. Simply write `\Huge {\LARGE \blindtext \par}` and you will get what you expect.

Comment: @KeksDose -- although the paragraph in question will have the desired baselines, the "outer" `\Huge` will remain to affect anything that follows.  not really a good idea.

Comment: If you write `\Huge`, you wanna have huge type somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(La)TeX "wraps" the preceding paragraph when it comes to `\par` or a blank line, and then it uses the characteristics of the font currently in effect.

your first paragraph doesn't "end" while `\LARGE` is in effect, so it uses the default baseline value.

but `\Huge` is at the outer level, so its baseline value is used for the second paragraph.
the `\LARGE` baseline value is never considered.

moral: if you want the baselines to be compatible with the font size in an isolated paragraph, always be sure to end the different-sized group with `\par` or a blank line.

Comment: I've marked up your inline code with `\``: using `\`` ...`'` doesn't work here :-)

Comment: @JosephWright -- aaarrrrghhhhh.  someday i'll learn to type correctly.  (too bad there's not a preview on comments.)