# baselineskip param of \fontsize doesn't add space between my lines

Tags: line-spacing, baseline

I'm setting baselineskip to a multiple of 4 times the fontsize and it's having not much of a difference from 1.2.  At 1.2 the text collides as well.

I'm making a flashcard app, so the text should be easy on the eyes.  It doesn't have to be compressed like newspaper text.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}{\fontsize{60}{240}\selectfont
I have baselineskip set to 4 in the fontsize macro, as you can see it doesn't seem to be doing much.  It would be nice to have some spaces in between these beautiful lines.  Thank you.}
\end{document}
```

Here's a picture of the output and my app:

[image]

Comment: this is a faq you ended the size change before the end of the paragraph, and it is the value of `\baselineskip` at the end of the paragraph that is used.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not sure what you mean.  I have {} around the content

Comment: exactly. If you remove those, you will get the correct space, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139873/what-are-the-most-common-mistakes-that-beginners-of-latex-and-friends-make/139898#139898

Comment: despite it being a FAQ and that answer being an answer, i can't find a good duplicate _question_ and your question is clear with a good small example so i think I'll answer it here:-)

Comment: try this for a duplicate: [Font sizes and line height: how/when/why do \Huge, \LARGE, etc. affect one or the other? ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36495/579]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
\fontsize{60}{240}\selectfont
```

the current font is changed and the current value of `\baselineskip` is set to 240pt, however TeX breaks paragraphs into lines at the end of the paragraph, and the inter-line space is added then so the value of `\baselineskip` is not used unless it is in scope at the end of the paragraph.

here you first have `}` (at which point `\baselineskip` resets to its original value) and then have the end of the paragraph.

In general you should always have a blank line or `\par`  before the `}` that closes a group for a font change so that a suitable lien spacing is used. An exception being something like `{\large this}` which intentionally squeezes a large word into the existing baseline spacing.

In this particular case, where there is no following text, a simpler solution is simply to omit the `{...}`

Comment: I'm a big fan of simple solutions :D