# Distancing between lines is inconsistent

Tags: line-spacing, leaflet

I am using the leaflet package, and on the first page I create two titles, a main big title and a smaller one.

This is a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[10pt,foldmark,notumble]{leaflet}
\renewcommand*\foldmarkrule{.3mm}
\renewcommand*\foldmarklength{5mm}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    
        \fontsize{30}{34}{\selectfont{}THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THE EARTH AND THE SKY}%
        
        \vspace{5em}
        
        \fontsize{23}{25}{\selectfont{}What does the it write this random text which is only a random text to test believing}
    
    \end{center}

    \newpage
    \section{Abstract}
    This is the abstract
    \section{Objectives}
    \lipsum[5-7]
    \section{Techniques}
    \lipsum[8-10]
    \section{Conclusions}
    \lipsum[14]

\end{document}
```

My questions are:

1. Notice the sub-title, the distance between the last two lines isn't equal to the first two. How can I fix it? Normal solutions I found after searching did not work..
2. How do I increase the distance between the lines of the main title?

[image]

Comment: The issue is entirely due to the fact that the lower case `y` descends below the baseline.

Comment: How can I increase the distancing between the lines to get rid of this artifact?

Comment: I would also lose setspce.  The **only** good reason to use setspace is if you are required to use "double spacing."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a good explanation for this (and maybe someone more educated will come by and tell us), but somehow your extraneous set of braces around your title/subtitle is suppressing the baselineskip value. (The result you showed is not what it should look like with font size of 30 and a baselineskip of 34.)

So: remove those extra braces. At least on my computer this restores the correctly specified baslineskip values.

---

#### Update

As [David Carlisle explains](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408541/baselineskip-param-of-fontsize-doesnt-add-space-between-my-lines#comment1019417_408541) the `baselineskip` used is the value in effect at the end of the paragraph. By putting your `\selectfont` inside a pair of braces, the selected `baselineskip` value was reverted before the end of the paragraph.

So

1. You can remove the braces that surrounds `{\selectfont{} ... }`
2. Alternatively, you can end the paragraph yourself by adding `{\selectfont{} ... \par}`

Either will work.