# Temporarily increase line spacing

Tags: paragraphs, line-spacing, grouping

How do I temporarily increase line spacing? I have some text on my title page:

```
\begin{center}
{ \Large \textbf{The Great Thesis About Some Very Great Things Indeed With
a Pretty Long Title That Will Probably Be Split Between at Least Two Lines
Or So} }
\end{center}
```

I'm finding that the line spacing here is too small, but it's fine elsewhere in the document. How can I make the spacing bigger for just this piece of text?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Simply end the paragraph before closing the group associated to \Large so the corresponding `\baselineskip` will be applied; you can do this by adding `\par`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\Large\textbf{The Great Thesis About Some Very Great Things Indeed With
a Pretty Long Title That Will Probably Be Split Between at Least Two Lines
Or So}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\Large\textbf{The Great Thesis About Some Very Great Things Indeed With
a Pretty Long Title That Will Probably Be Split Between at Least Two Lines
Or So}\par
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Here's a comparison of both results:

[image]

I removed the outer braces since they are not necessary, as the `center` environment already forms a group.

If you want to have more control over the spacing, you could use the second argument of `\fontsize` (the first argument gives the font size); a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{15pt}{15pt}\selectfont\bfseries The Great Thesis About Some Very Great Things Indeed With a Pretty Long Title That Will Probably Be Split Between at Least Two Lines
Or So
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{15pt}{18pt}\selectfont\bfseries The Great Thesis About Some Very Great Things Indeed With a Pretty Long Title That Will Probably Be Split Between at Least Two Lines
Or So
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{15pt}{30pt}\selectfont\bfseries The Great Thesis About Some Very Great Things Indeed With a Pretty Long Title That Will Probably Be Split Between at Least Two Lines
Or So
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

producing now:

[image]

Another option, not requiring you to explicitly know the font size, is to change the factor in the mandatory argument of `\linespread`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\linespread{1}\Large\bfseries The Great Thesis About Some Very Great Things Indeed With a Pretty Long Title That Will Probably Be Split Between at Least Two Lines
Or So
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\linespread{0.8}\Large\bfseries The Great Thesis About Some Very Great Things Indeed With a Pretty Long Title That Will Probably Be Split Between at Least Two Lines
Or So
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\linespread{2}\Large\bfseries The Great Thesis About Some Very Great Things Indeed With a Pretty Long Title That Will Probably Be Split Between at Least Two Lines
Or So
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Yet another option is a redefinition of `\baselinestretch`; the following code will produce the same result illustrated just above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\Large\bfseries The Great Thesis About Some Very Great Things Indeed With a Pretty Long Title That Will Probably Be Split Between at Least Two Lines
Or So
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{0.8}\Large\bfseries The Great Thesis About Some Very Great Things Indeed With a Pretty Long Title That Will Probably Be Split Between at Least Two Lines
Or So
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{2}\Large\bfseries The Great Thesis About Some Very Great Things Indeed With a Pretty Long Title That Will Probably Be Split Between at Least Two Lines
Or So
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Finally, there's the [setspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package which offers you a series of commands and environments to change "in a sensible way" the value of `\baselineskip`.

Comment: You can also use `setspace` package that provides `\singlespacing`, `\onehalfspacing` and `\doublespacing` commands.

Comment: @HarishKumar: yes; I've added the package also to my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding `setspace`, be careful with this! Just by including the package (without using any commands of it), it destroyed the layout for me in some places.

Comment: One more note which caused me 10 min googling: If `\linespread{..}` is used without changing font size/style afterwards, then a `\selectfont` must follow.

Comment: @neo: should write a separate answer

Comment: @neo, thanks to your comment and effort, I found the solution in 2 minutes. Great comment.

Answer (score 8):

that text is set with normal linespacing with a large font, you need to ensure the end of the pargraph is in the scope of the size change. Remove the brace at the start and end of the environment.

Comment: Unfortunately, that makes it a tad too big. How can I just customize the spacing to my needs in this particular place?

Comment: The other answer has since been edited to cover that case.