# no effect of \baselinestretch

Tags: line-spacing

I'm probably doing something wrong, but i can't see any effect of the command `\baselinestretch`, which should modify the vspace between lines. I read somewhere, that i should add `\selectfont` after it, but i can't see any effect either:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}\selectfont coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou }

\end{document}
```

Comment: You're issuing `\par` when the setting of `\baselinestretch` has been forgotten because the group has ended. Put `\par` before the closing brace.

Comment: May be http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48741/temporarily-increase-line-spacing/48743#comment100708_48743 is of some help?

Answer (score 13):

This problem is similar to when one writes

```
{\Large some long text
 that will span two or
 more lines}
```

and the line spacing comes out wrong.

TeX uses *one* baseline skip for *all* lines in a paragraph, using the value in force when it scans the end of paragraph. In the example and also in your code the `\par` (or equivalent blank line) is found when the group where the change has been issued has already been closed and its effect canceled. The following code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

{\linespread{2}\selectfont coucou coucou coucou coucou 
coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou 
coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou 
coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou coucou \par}

\end{document}
```

won't have the problem. Notice the `\linespread{2}` command, which is handier than `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}` and has the same effect.