# Cannot temporarily increase line spacing

Tags: titles, line-spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Temporarily increase line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48741/temporarily-increase-line-spacing)

I tried to follow these examples here [Temporarily increase line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48741/temporarily-increase-line-spacing) but in my case it didn't change anything.

I have to use a latex template, which is provided by my university. My title looks currently like this:

[image]

as you can see, the third line has not enough spacing. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

You find the entire template (already with my title in it) for downloading on my webspace:
http://www.easteregg.ch/DDIS-diploma-thesis-template-en-long-title.zip

just run the "ddis-thesis-EN.tex" in the root folder and you will get probably the exact same issue.

Comment: Please don't link to a zip file: make a small tex file that _only_ makes the problem text and post as a working Example (MWE). Looking at your output it looks like your input has the same error as in the question that you link to. Make sure that the scope of the size change includes a blank line or `\par`.

Comment: it is not possible to create a MWE since the template provided by my university uses subfolders in order to create the entire output file.

Comment: While I don't get bold and sans-serif output with the template you provided, the line spacing *is* correct as soon as I add a `\par` after "Crowdsourcing" in `title.tex`.

Answer (score 0):

User "lockstep" provided the info I needed. The tag **\par** had to be added within the brackets (I tried to add it outside of them).