# Changing linespacing in Chinese

Tags: xetex, line-spacing

I am going to write a document containing Chinese and English words. However, the linespaces for the two different language are not the same. Now, I take "[Temporarily increase line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48741/temporarily-increase-line-spacing)" as the reference to change the linespace for the lines with Chinese characters. Here is my code (Note that I typeset the document with XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

% Setting the Chinese fonts. 
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{BiauKai}
\newCJKfontfamily\bfKai{楷體-繁 粗體}

\usepackage{times}

% Setting the linebreak for Chinese font.
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh"  
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt 

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\bfKai{摘要} (Abstract)}

\setlength{\baselineskip}{20pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{abstract}
    \linespread{1.2} 本研究的重點在於利用JRA-25再分析資料來模擬颱風的活動，並找出不同偵測和軌跡的檢測方案如何影響模擬的結果。  \\[0.3cm]
    \linespread{1} The study is to use JRA-25 reanalysis data to find how the activities of simulated tropical cyclones (TCs) is affected by different detection and trajectory schemes.
    \end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

But the command `\linespread{1.2}` before the Chinese sentences is not working at all. How to fix the problem?

[image: result]

Thank you!

Comment: `\linespread{1.2}\selectfont`

Comment: @egreg Still not working...