# \LARGE{\textbf{...}} vs \textbf{\LARGE{...}}

Tags: formatting

I am currently writing a project report, and have come across a strange thing.

While making the title page, when I insert the title,
if I wrote `\textbf{\LARGE{Multi-Server Authentication Scheme Using Biometrics}}`
the output came as this:

[image: less line height, so looks cramped]

But if I change the code to `\LARGE{\textbf{Multi-Server Authentication Scheme Using Biometrics}}`, the output looks like this:

[image: more line height, looks perfect]

Although the above solved my problem, I am curious to know why this happens. The rest of the code needed to fully reproduce this is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{here goes the above codes for the title}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
{\bfseries\LARGE Multi-Server Authentication Scheme Using Biometrics}

{\bfseries\LARGE Multi-Server Authentication Scheme Using Biometrics\par}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the linespacing the current font size at *the end* of a paragraph is important! And, of course, `\Large` is a switch and has *no* arguments!

Comment: I tried this code, but it's not compiling. The error says `Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete.
<to be read again> 
`

Comment: @AbhisekChaudhuri: `\LARGE \textbf{Multi-Server Authentication Scheme Using Biometrics}` or `{\bfseries \LARGE Multi-Server Authentication Scheme Using Biometrics \par}` will give you the  desired output. For a more in-depth explanation you can have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48743/134144

Comment: @AbhisekChaudhuri: Ah, I posted the wrong code. See edited answer