# How to reduce line spacing in single-paragraph biblatex bibliography with a small font size

Tags: biblatex, fontsize, line-spacing

I'm trying to create a compressed, single-paragraph bibliography using `biblatex`, like in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8071/32888). I'd also like to make the font quite a bit smaller than the main font size of the document. I'm doing this by setting `\bibfont`; however, this produces something that looks like double spacing, but I only want single spacing. I thought that

```
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\fontsize{5pt}{7pt}\selectfont}
```

would take care of this because `\fontsize` is supposed to also set the `\baselineskip` value. Does anyone know why I have such big line spacing in the bibliography, and how can I reduce this spacing to something that just looks like normal single spacing?

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a1,
  author = {Smith, Jane},
  journal = {Nature},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {201--204},
  year = {1999},
}
@article{a2,
  author = {Smith, Jane},
  journal = {Nature},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {201--204},
  year = {2000},
}
@article{a3,
  author = {Smith, Jane},
  journal = {Nature},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {201--204},
  year = {2001},
}
@article{a4,
  author = {Smith, Jane},
  journal = {Nature},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {201--204},
  year = {2002},
}
@article{a5,
  author = {Smith, Jane},
  journal = {Nature},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {201--204},
  year = {2003},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxnames=1,
  minnames=1,
  firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\fontsize{5pt}{7pt}\selectfont}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {}
  {}
  {\addspace}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Image showing the large spacing between bibliography items]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that, if horizontal mode is not ended in the bibliography environment, then the value of `\baselineskip` reverts to what it is elsewhere in the document. This is discussed in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554954/32888) to [Reduce line spacing when using smaller font size in an environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/554286/32888).

You can end the paragraph (i.e., end horizontal mode and force the material to be broken into lines) by putting `\endgraf` into the `<end code>` part of the `\defbibenvironment` command:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {}
  {\endgraf}
  {\addspace}
```

You have to use `\endgraf` here instead of `\par`, otherwise you'll get an error (see [When is it better to use \par than \endgraf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96865/32888) for some discussion of the differences between `\par` and `\endgraf`).

Here is the full MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{a1,
  author = {Smith, Jane},
  journal = {Nature},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {201-204},
  year = {1999},
}
@article{a2,
  author = {Smith, Jane},
  journal = {Nature},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {201-204},
  year = {2000},
}
@article{a3,
  author = {Smith, Jane},
  journal = {Nature},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {201-204},
  year = {2001},
}
@article{a4,
  author = {Smith, Jane},
  journal = {Nature},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {201-204},
  year = {2002},
}
@article{a5,
  author = {Smith, Jane},
  journal = {Nature},
  volume = {7},
  pages = {201-204},
  year = {2003},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-comp,
  maxcitenames=2,
  maxnames=1,
  minnames=1,
  firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\fontsize{5pt}{7pt}\selectfont}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {}
  {\endgraf}
  {\addspace}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And here is the resulting output with something that looks like single line spacing:

[image]