# Different line spacing in two different paragraphs

Tags: babel, line-spacing

I have two paragraphs; one in spanish and the other in english. The problem is that the english paragraph has more line spacing than the other (I would like that both have the line spacing of the spanish one):

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
  }

\begin{document}

{\footnotesize \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} Copyleft: Esta obra es
  libre; puede redistribuirla o modificarla de acuerdo con los
  términos de la Licencia Arte Libre
  \url{https://artlibre.org/licence/lal/en/}.

  Copyleft: This is a free work; you can copy, distribute, and modify
  it under the terms of the Free Art License
  \url{https://artlibre.org/licence/lal/en/}.  }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to end the paragraph by using `\par` before closing the group associated to `\footnotesize`.

Related question:
[Temporarily increase line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48741/temporarily-increase-line-spacing)

The following code will produce the intended output:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=black,
filecolor=magenta,
urlcolor=blue,
}

\begin{document}

{\footnotesize\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  Copyleft: Esta obra es libre; puede redistribuirla o modificarla de
  acuerdo con los términos de la Licencia Arte Libre
  \url{https://artlibre.org/licence/lal/en/}.

  Copyleft: This is a free work; you can copy, distribute, and modify
  it under the terms of the Free Art License
  \url{https://artlibre.org/licence/lal/en/}.\par}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: yes or like the first paragraoh, just leave a blank line rather than `\par` (I'd use `\par` in package code and a blanl line in a document)

Comment: @Rui Antunes: Thanks! Works great!