# Weird horizontal spacing after displayed equation

Tags: math-mode, spacing

As you can see, this is an excerpt from a submission to a journal.
I am using the {\small } command to fit the equation into one line, albeit at the expense of its number falling onto the next line.

The problem is this undesired space at the beginning of the line right after the displayed equation. Clearly, using \hspace is not a good practice.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{e-jc}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
{\small
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn:lemma_proof}
    k
    =
    \frac{ f(b) - f(a) }{ g(b) - g(a) }
    \quad
    \text{and}
    \quad
    \ell
    =
    \frac{ f(a) g(b) - f(b) g(a) }{ g(b) - g(a) }
    =
    \frac{ f(c) g(b) - f(c) g(a) - f(b) g(c) + f(a) g(c) }{ g(b) - g(a) },
\end{equation}
}
%\hspace{-4mm}
where the last equality follows from
We can easily
verify that $R(a)=R(b)=0$ and $R(c)=0$ by using the first representation for
$\ell$ and the second representation for $\ell$, respectively.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @campa, don't worry. I learned with your comments too. I'll delete my comment to avoid propagate this bad habit.

Comment: hm, I think while the linked question does answer this one (by showing the "proper" way how to make equations etc. small), the actual bug is either [symbols - What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat?noredirect=1&lq=1) or  [paragraphs - Temporarily increase line spacing - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48741/temporarily-increase-line-spacing/48743#48743)

Comment: @campa, not really. I _am_ wrapping the equation environment into {\small }, so not sure what your suggestion was.

Comment: @azazello The problem is the missing `%` after `}` in line 21

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, Oh, for crying out loud, what's that about? Does LaTeX process spaces at the end of the line or the end-of-line symbol? I never knew that. 

How do I upvote you or make your answer the accepted one? Thank you so very much. :-)

Comment: @azazello The end of line acts as a space in latex.

Comment: @azazello ... and no need to mark anything as accepted, the linked duplicate already has nice answers which explain the % business in more detail