# Remove page number from book title

Tags: header-footer

How to remove page number from  book title? 
I tried `thispagestyle{empty}` command, but this only works for article document.

[image]

This is my sample code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper  , 12 pt, titlepage]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
%\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\DisemulatePackage{setspace}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
%\usepackage{pst-node,graphicx}
%\SpecialCoor
\usepackage[top=4cm, bottom=3cm, left=4cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{arabtex}
%\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{<after-sep>}

\usepackage[space]{grffile}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

% untuk meletakkan float di daerah tertentu
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{pstrick}
%\usepackage{pst-all}
%\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
%\usepackage[pdflatex]{pstricks}
%\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}


  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
  \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  \titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter 
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering \chapter{XXX}
\begin{center}
\vspace{0.6 cm }
\begin{large}
\textbf{TESIS} \\
\end{large}
\vspace{0.3  cm}
\begin{large}
Karya tulis sebagai salah satu syarat \\ untuk memperoleh gelar Magister dari \\  Institut Teknologi Bandung \\
\end{large}
\vspace{1.5 cm}
\begin{large}
Oleh\\
\textbf{SASASASAS} \\
NIM: 20211019\\
(Program Studi Magister Fisika)\\ 
\end{large}
\vspace{1.4 cm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{logo_itb.jpg}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5 cm}
\begin{center}
INSTITUT TEKNOLOGI BANDUNG \\
2013
\end{center}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you use `maketitle`? If that is so, write \thispagestyle{empty} `immediately after` \maketitle.

Comment: No, I not used `\maketitle`, that page I write manually and I placed it in `\frontmatter` content of the book.

Comment: Did you use `\begin{titlepage} ... \end{titlepage}`?

Comment: Yes, I use that, and all the contents of the page, I place in between

Comment: Leave out the \frontmatter in title page, it's meant for the foreword.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: OK, I add my MWE...

Comment: I can see the issue with your example, when … Some advices: Remove every not needed and therefore commented package entry, but remove also all other packages not needed for showing the issue. Use for images either the `demo` option of `graphicx` package or (preferred) an image from package `mwe` (most basic `example-image.png`). Please read everything in [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). And `\begin{large}…\end{large}` is also not corrrect, cf. [How to use \Large and its variants](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7312). Package `float` is loaded twice.

Comment: No, package `float` is even loaded three times. Once is enough.

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is, that you use `\chapter` for the title. This switches to `\pagestyle{plain}` instead of the empty pagestyle for a titlepage.

You had some other issues I fixed in code below:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt,titlepage]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=4cm, bottom=3cm, left=4cm, right=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\Huge XXX}
\vspace{0.6cm}

\begingroup % better readable then just writing "{"
\large
\textbf{TESIS}
\vspace{0.3cm}

Karya tulis sebagai salah satu syarat \\ untuk memperoleh gelar Magister dari \\  Institut Teknologi Bandung \\
\vspace{1.5cm}

Oleh\\
\textbf{SASASASAS}\\
NIM: 20211019\\
(Program Studi Magister Fisika)
\vspace{1.4cm}
\endgroup % instead of "}"

\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{example-image.png}
\vspace{0.5cm}

INSTITUT TEKNOLOGI BANDUNG\\
2013
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

First, there is actually no environment `large`, cf. [How to use \Large and its variants](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/). Put `\large` into a group instead.

Second, there is no need to set `\vspace` outside of environment `center`. This makes the code harder to read.

*And some general advices:* As I already wrote in my comment: For a minimal (not) working example remove every not needed package. Remove also all commented lines, as long they are not explaining something. Use for example publicly available images – preferred are images from package [`mwe`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) – or the `demo` option from package `graphicx`.

Answer (score 0):

This does not produce a page number on page 1 for me:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{book}




\begin{document}


\begin{titlepage}
Hello
\end{titlepage}



hi

\end{document}
```