# How to set the fontsize in a Qtree script?

Tags: fontsize, qtree

I'm looking for a way to make the main font bigger than the default size (just biiiiig all the way). I'm a total LateX noob and already tried and failed anything I found online. (e.g. the posts already asking this question about tikz-qtree, which I have no idea what it is)

Here's my body:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\\begin{document}
\Tree  [here goes my nice tree blablablalballalb]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `qtree` package allows you to define two hooks for formatting the labels and the leaf nodes of the tree. They are `\qlabelhook` and `\qleafhook`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\newcommand{\qlabelhook}{\Large}
\newcommand{\qleafhook}{\Large\itshape}
\begin{document}

\Tree  [.AP [.XP X ] [.BP [.CP C ] [.D D ] ]]

\end{document}
```

[image: qtree tree]

However, if you are new to LaTeX I would not recommend using `qtree`. It is an old package that has largely been superseded by either `tikz-qtree` or the even more powerful `forest` package.  I would recommend using the latter.  Here's the same tree using `forest`. Notice the slight change in the syntax (there is no `.` in labels, and leaf nodes also need to be bracketed.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}for tree={font=\Large}, for leaves={font=\Large\itshape}
[AP [XP [X] ] [BP [CP [C] ] [D [D] ]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: forest tree]

Answer (score 2):

Qtree doesn't set the font size unless you tell it to. If you want the entire tree to be in a larger (or smaller) size, just switch the font size before beginning the tree:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\\begin{document}
{\Large
\Tree  [here [.VP goes [.NP my nice tree ] blablablalballalb ] ]
\par}
\end{document}
```

Better yet, you can use LaTeX environment syntax instead of TeX brackets:

```
\begin{Large}
\Tree  [here [.VP goes [.NP my nice tree ] blablablalballalb ] ]
\end{Large}
```

If in fact you want to control the font size of selected parts of the tree, use the formatting hooks `\qlabelhook` and `\qleafhook` as Alan Munn shows in his answer. (Or use a different tree package, as he also suggests.)

Comment: I tried this initially but it creates odd vertical spacing issues compared to the `\qlabelhook` solution.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't aware of that, thanks. I didn't try this code today, but it's my standard solution when a tree needs to be smaller... I'll have to look into it, perhaps it only works well for smaller sizes.

Comment: It is certainly ***not*** `better yet` to treat a switch as an environment. This will work, but it is misleading because there is no environment here. `\Large` is a switch. Better by far to treat it as such in your code rather than obscuring its kind to no purpose.

Comment: @cfr, I guess it is a question of taste, but I'll raise you [this SO question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/how-to-use-large-and-its-variants) and the first comment to the (well-upvoted) accepted answer, which points out that using switches as environments is endorsed in Leslie Lamport's book. Despite the caveats (idem.), I consider the environment syntax to be more in the spirit of latex style than the TeX `{\switch ...}` syntax.