# Beamer - How to make URL big?

Tags: beamer, fontsize, urls

Consider the following example. I want to make the website address ***very big***. I have tried things like \Large etc. but to no avail. I think because of the URL command. How can I keep the formatting of the URL command, which I like, but make the font size bigger?

For your information, I have included my full preamble before beginning the document in case I need to add packages etc.

Thanks

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
   \oldmacro\hfill%
   \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}  % to remove the interactive buttons

% Additional packages needed
\usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{dsfont}  % For mathds font
\usepackage{hologo}  % For BibTeX font
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Points of information}
\framesubtitle{1. Contact details}
Website:

\begin{center}
\url{WWW.URL.COM}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try: `\Large{\url{WWW.URL.COM}}`

Comment: Where exactly have you inserted `\Large` and friends? I added it in side the center, works just fine. Given the font size used in this MWE, you probably need to use a larger side, .e.g. `\huge` to notive a change

Comment: That did not work unfortunately. However! I tried messing around some more, it seems if I put \LARGE before a word, it does work, including the URL. But "large" has to be all caps otherwise it doesn't work. Is there a reason for this? Maybe a package I'm missing?

Comment: @naphaneal, it's `{\Large whatever}`... `\Large` is a switch, not a command.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/how-to-use-large-and-its-variants/7313

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\large\url{..}` works fine, but the difference between the font sizes is not very big. However if you place booth variants below each other, you'll see the change.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\url{WWW.URL.COM}

\large\url{WWW.URL.COM}

\Large\url{WWW.URL.COM}

\LARGE\url{WWW.URL.COM}

\fontsize{48}{56}\selectfont\url{WWW.URL.COM}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At this large size, you may need to add kerning around the dot.