# How to automatically identify the location of the last line of the body-of-text output on a given page, after nowidow has taken effect?

Tags: page, widows-orphans, body

I have a document that has `\usepackage[all]{nowidow}` in order to eliminate all widows and orphans.

This sometimes causes lots of white space between the bottom of the body of text and the footer. I dislike this white space, but I wish to keep `\usepackage[all]{nowidow}`.

My initial strategy to eliminate the white space was to find a way to have the footer move to always be just below the body of text --- jump up and down, as it were --- *after* removal of all widows and orphans. I did not see a way of doing this, however; so I asked SE.

In response to that question ([How to make footer move to just below the body of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690073/how-to-make-footer-move-to-just-below-the-body-of-text)), I have been told that it is difficult to automatically have the footer jump up and down in the way I have described.

Therefore, my new strategy is to forget about the real footer entirely, and instead, if possible, **first** to have LaTeX automatically identify the location of the last line of the actual body-of-text output on a given page *after `nowidow` has taken effect*, **then** to place `\thepage`, centered, one `\baselineskip` below that location. (For all I had wanted in my footer was `\thepage`.)

How might I do this, if possible? Or if impossible, why is that, exactly?

I am aware that my attitude toward widows and orphans (eliminating them all) and footers and quasi-footers (wanting them to jump around) is abominable in the eyes of many.

You can see the annoyingly large white space at the bottom of pages 2, 7, 27, 31, 33, 36, and 38 of the following MWE. This is simply illustrative, for, I repeat, my new strategy does not involve using a real footer.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4.25in, paperheight=5.5in, footskip=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=0pt, indent=20pt]{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow} % Eliminates orphans and widows
\usepackage{lipsum}

\emergencystretch 30pt % Causes text to better heed margin

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{{\small[} \oldstylenums{\thepage} {\small]}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-70]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you considered using `lua-widow-control`? ([Article](https://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/151108/ZpravodajCSTUG_032-2022-1_6.pdf), [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-widow-control)) It doesn't solve the specific problem in the question, but it should prevent the too-short pages entirely. I'd say it's the best solution for removing widows and orphans, but I'm probably a little biased as its author :)

Comment: this is hard (and pretty weird) as page breaking happens asynchronously so you do not know which line will be last on the page at the time any macro in the text are evaluated, only later in the output routine (when float and page head and foot added) so you need to modify the page foot code to (try to) detect white space at the end of the page and back up. That is not generally possible unless using luatex

Comment: This is a mater of taste, but maybe instead of avoid  paragraph skips  (`[skip=0pt]`), orphans and widows at any  cost (`[all]`), so forcing big gaps somewhere,  and then try to dissimulate that moving the footers, you could allow some small paragraph skip glue (x pt plus y pt minus z pt)),  and  allow even a bit of  flexibility in the baseline skips and  any other possible glue.  As more flexibility you allow, less noticeable gaps you will find trough all the document.