# How can I change the font size of my table?

Tags: tables, fonts, size

For my thesis I am trying to adjust the font size of my tables in LaTeX. However, I struggle to have a scriptize font size for my caption and for the entries in my table.

Here's my code. I hope anyone can help!

```
%begin table
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,size=footnotesize}
     \caption{Test table}
    \label{table:7}
    \begin{tabular}{ l | l }
 \textbf{Entry 1} & \textbf{Entry 2} \\ \cline{1-2}
 Entry 3 & Entry 4 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{scriptsize}
```

Comment: I'd probably just add a font size command such as `\scriptsize ` inside the `table` environment. The redefinition will be local and so only the table will be `\scriptsize`.

Comment: `scriptsize`  is not an environment. correct use is to add `\scriptsize` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @moewe Arg, I did forget about the group around it. Thanks a lot for your comment!

Comment: Technically `\begin{scriptsize} foo \end{scriptsize}` usually works fine for text because of the way environments are implemented in LaTeX, but I would usually suggest to go with `{\scriptsize foo}` instead. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7312/35864.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption, array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \scriptsize
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,size=scriptsize}
     \caption{Test table}
    \label{table:7}
    \begin{tabular}{ l | l }
 \textbf{Entry 1} & \textbf{Entry 2} \\ \cline{1-2}
 Entry 3 & Entry 4 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great this codes works indeed, thanks a lot!