# My figure does not appear on the right frame of a beamer slide! Please help!

Tags: diagrams, minipage

I inserted a figure through minipage. I want it to appear on the sixth frame of the slide but instead, it appears on the nineth. 
here is the code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 

\frametitle{some title}

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \visible<1-10>{1}
    \begin{itemize}
     \item \visible<2-10> {subitem}
       \vspace*{+1mm}  
     \begin{itemize}\begin{footnotesize}
     \item \visible<3-10>{{\only<10>{\color{red}} {subsubitem \hyperlink{project_A}{\beamerskipbutton{Project A} }} }
    \item\visible<4-10>{subsubitem \hyperlink{project_B}{\beamerskipbutton{Project B}}}
    \item \visible<5-10>{subsubitem\hyperlink{project_C}{\beamerskipbutton{Project C}} }}
    \item[]
    \end{footnotesize}\end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

    \vspace*{+4mm}    

    \item \visible<1-10> {2}

  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.70\textwidth}

    \begin{itemize}

    \item \visible<6-10> {subitem} 

    \begin{itemize}

   \begin{footnotesize}

    \item \visible<7-10>{{\only<10>{\color{red}} {subsubitem \hyperlink{project_D}{\beamerskipbutton{Project D}}} }

 \item <8-10> {subsubitem} 
    \hyperlink{project_E}{\beamerskipbutton{Project E} } } 

\item <9-10> {subsubitem  \hyperlink{project_F}{\beamerskipbutton{Project F}}\hypertarget<10>{label}{}}

    \end{footnotesize}    

\end{itemize}   
\end{itemize} 
\end{minipage}

 \hfill

  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.20\textwidth}

      \includegraphics[width=0.78\textwidth]{PICTURE.PNG} 

\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example document compilable. If your document results in error messages, please do not look at the output but try to fix the errors (or at least include a hint on them in your question). `footnote` is not an environment but a switch. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7312/134144

Comment: thank you! now is compilable :)

Answer (score 3):

In the following example, I have replaced `\begin{footnote}` and `\end{footnote}`  by `\footnote`. To show  the image from slide 6 onwards, I have used `\visible`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 

\frametitle{some title}

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \visible<1-10>{1}
    \begin{itemize}
     \item \visible<2-10> {subitem}
       \vspace*{+1mm}  
     \begin{itemize}\begin{footnotesize}
     \item \visible<3-10>{{\only<10>{\color{red}} {subsubitem \hyperlink{project_A}{\beamerskipbutton{Project A} }} }
    \item\visible<4-10>{subsubitem \hyperlink{project_B}{\beamerskipbutton{Project B}}}
    \item \visible<5-10>{subsubitem \hyperlink{project_C}{\beamerskipbutton{Project C}} }}
    \item[]
    \end{footnotesize}\end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}

    \vspace*{+4mm}    

    \item \visible<1-10> {2}

  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.70\textwidth}

    \begin{itemize}

    \item \visible<6-10> {subitem} 

    \begin{itemize}

   %\begin{footnotesize}
 \footnotesize
    \item \visible<7-10>{{\only<10>{\color{red}} {subsubitem \hyperlink{project_D}{\beamerskipbutton{Project D}}} }

 \item <8-10> {subsubitem} 
    \hyperlink{project_E}{\beamerskipbutton{Project E} } } 

\item <9-10> {subsubitem  \hyperlink{project_F}{\beamerskipbutton{Project F}}\hypertarget<10>{label}{}}

    %\end{footnotesize}    

\end{itemize}   
\end{itemize} 
\end{minipage}

 \hfill

  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.20\textwidth}

       \visible<6-10>{\includegraphics[width=0.78\textwidth]{example-image} }

\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```